# How can I remove Cortana, Store and Message from 10

Tags: cortana

Windows 10 loads Cortana and Store in my task manager even though I have disabled them. After trying to rid myself of them I am at a loss. The problem is they also load in Zoom Text, the program I use for screen reader and magnification as I am legally blind. Is there any way to get rid of them without blowing up 10?